# Can't run Vidalia due to an AppArmor policy error

Tags: gconf, vidalia

I installed Vidalia , and added a user to debian-tor group.

But when I run it , it gets me error:

```
$ vidalia 

(process:5691): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

(<unknown>:5691): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried it:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia
sudo /etc/init.d/tor start
```

Ok , now vidalia works fine:

```
$ vidalia
```

Comment: works but what does it do ?

Comment: @TiloBunt as far as I know vidalia needs permission or access to something that `apparmor` doesn't allow. have a look into http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php?title=FAQ&oldid=7412#What_is_AppArmor.3F it will tells you what is `apparmor`

Comment: here a site which explain the CMD: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-howto-disable-apparmor-commands/  before running your workaround check via  $ sudo apparmor_status  would be a good idea and confirm afterwards that it's disabled