# Vidalia won't start

Tags: 14.04, tor, vidalia

I have installed tor and vidalia using

```
sudo apt-get install tor vidalia
```

but when I click on Vidalia from the Unity Launcher, nothing happens.

Why is that? What's the problem? Thanks.

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What happenes when you run `vidalia` from the terminal? (ctrl+alt+t)

Comment: What happens is that AppArmor is blocking Vidalia. Try to launch vidalia from a terminal and you'll se the error message.

Comment: Try to do Tim and anonymouscoward suggestion that you may know the symptoms of problem.  If it's caused by apparmor issue, you may try this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/449824/cant-run-vidalia-due-to-an-apparmor-policy-error

Answer (score 3):

I have had success installing and running vidalia following these steps.

First you'll need to get a vidalia package that works. The package in the software center doesn't work. In the comments you'll find a post by Zachery Thomas Winch, 2014-10-21 :

[Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/universe/base/vidalia) is a fix

### Download one of these packages. It works on 14.04

It works with a little work.

Then purge tor and vidalia.

```
sudo apt-get purge tor vidalia
```

make sure that the `/etc/tor/torrc` file is gone.
In you home directory make sure that the folder `~/.vidalia` is gone. You will probably have to delete this.

Add the tor project to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list and add this to the bottom.
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

then install tor

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Then find the vidalia package you downloaded earlier and open it in software center and install it. after its done run vidalia.

Thats it. I have noticed that vidalia doesn't like to start the tor service(tor runs a startup). if you need to start or stop the tor service I use

```
sudo service tor stop
```

then kill vidalia

```
sudo service tor start
```

then start vidalia

Side note, I have been trying to do this for days and I cant remember if I had to add the gpg key. Im pretty sure I did but I cant remember so if the above doesn't work try adding the add the gpg key. you can get instructions from [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en)

Comment: Please review my edits: use 4 spaces in front of a line you wqnt to come up `like this` and use backticks "`" for what I just did...  ;-)  Excellent answer BTW, I've voted it up!

Comment: Thank you very much Fabby, I've been wanting to do this for a while but haven't hat the points to do so. I will take note of your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is obsolete / outdated (probably Vidalia 0.2.21-1). please download the newer one directly from :

[tor browser bundle](http://www.upubuntu.com/2014/04/install-tor-browser-bundle-354-stable.html)

Comment: that one should work link http://www.upubuntu.com/2014/04/install-tor-browser-bundle-354-stable.html

Comment: The above link didn't work. It is the same Browser Bundle that I already have, except an older version.