# Chromium does not launch on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: chromium, 18.04

Chromium does not complete its launch, just hangs with the error messages below. Help wanted.

```
tob@monte-carlo:~$ chromium  
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" 
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.  
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.69" (uid=1000 pid=2206 comm="/snap/chromium/274/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)")  
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.secrets" (uid=1000 pid=1567 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login " label="unconfined")
```

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449824/cant-run-vidalia-due-to-an-apparmor-policy-error

Answer (score 0):

Resolved now. I tried removing and purging chromium, but it was not enough. I had to remove some file with chromium in its name under the ./snap/ directory.